# Construction of conditionally convergent series with certain property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Question**: It is given that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, but not absolutely convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$. Denote by $s_k$ the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^k a_n$, $k=1,2,... $

then " **it is possible**"  that $s_k>0$ for all but a finite number of values of k ?

**My attempt**:

Define $$
s_k=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if $k=2,3$ }\\[4pt]
\frac1{k}&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then clearly $s_k>0$ for all but a finite number of values of k (as required)

Further, $s_k$ converges to $0$ and  hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$.

But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is not absolutely convergent (**how can i prove it?**)

**Am i correct**? Please help me

Comment: You choose a $k$th partial sum. That's good. What is the $k$th term of your series?

Comment: @MMM i think for $k≥5$ we have $a_k= \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1}$

Comment: But then your $a_k$ are eventually negative, which is a contradiction as this implies $\sum |a_k|<\infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if $s_n$ decreases to $0$ after some finite point, let's call it $N,$ then we have

$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}(s_n-s_{n+1}) = s_N.$$

But the $n$th summand here is $-a_{n+1}$ and is nonnegative. It follows that  $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|a_{n+1}| < \infty,$ which is a contradiction.

I think the following idea works: We consider a series of the form

$$1-\frac{1}{2}+a_3 +\frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4}+a_6 +\frac{1}{5}- \frac{1}{6}+a_9+\cdots $$

Choose $a_3,a_6,\dots$ as follows

$$a_3 = \frac{1}{2}-1+\frac{1}{3!},$$ $$a_6 = \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3!}+ \frac{1}{6!},$$ $$ a_9 = \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6!} +\frac{1}{9!}, \dots$$

The idea is that $a_{3n}$ cancels out all previous summands, and then adds in the small amount of $1/(3n)!$ (which could be replaced by any positive sequence $\to 0.$) Note that $s_{3n}=1/(3n!)$ for all $n.$
.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate your idea. I computed few terms of the sequence of partial sum $(s_k)$ (where $s_k=a_1+...+a_k$) of the series that you written in your answer. I saw $s_1=1$, $s_2=1/2$, $s_3= 1/3!$, $s_4= 1/2$, $s_5=1/4$, $s_6=1/6!$....So none of terms in sequence $(s_k)$ are $≤0$. But question asked "is it possible" that $s_k>0$ for all but a finite number of values of k. That is there are some values of $k$ for which $s_k≤0$.

Comment: "all but a finite number" usually includes "all". After all $s_k>0$ for all $k$ is the strongest result. If for some reason you want $s_k\le 0$ for say $k=1,2,\dots ,6$ you can take  $-1+1-1+1-1+1+a_1+a_2+\cdots,$ where $a_1+a_2+a_3 \dots$ is my series.